# Python OpenCV Perspective transformation problems

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, transformation, perspective

I am trying to make a perspective transformation with opencv.
I want to extract screen from my e-book and align it.

[image: 1]

First, I found a biggest contour and put it **screenCnt2** variable.
After that I extracted values to 2 lists:

```
x1_1 = [i[0] for j in screenCnt2 for i in j]
y1_1 = [i[1] for j in screenCnt2 for i in j]
```

Then, I calculated max_width and max_height of my subimage inside contours:

```
len_yr = np.sqrt((x1_1[1] - x1_1[0]) ** 2 + (y1_1[0] - y1_1[1])**2)
len_rb = np.sqrt((x1_1[1] - x1_1[2])**2 + (y1_1[2] - y1_1[1])**2)
len_bg = np.sqrt((x1_1[2] - x1_1[3])**2 + (y1_1[2] - y1_1[3])**2)
len_gy = np.sqrt((y1_1[3] - y1_1[0])**2 + (x1_1[0] - x1_1[3])**2)
print(len_yr, len_rb, len_bg, len_gy)
max_width = max(int(len_yr), int(len_bg))
max_height = max(int(len_gy), int(len_rb))
```

And finally apply perspective transforming

```
p1 = [i for i in zip(x1_1,y1_1)]
pts1 = np.float32(p1)
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[max_width - 1,0],[max_width - 1, max_height - 1],[0, max_height -1 ]])


M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)
dst2 = cv2.warpPerspective(seg_im3, M, (max_width, max_height))

x1_2 = [i[0] for i in pts2]
y1_2 = [i[1] for i in pts2]

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(angle_im2[:, :, ::-1]),plt.title('Input')
plt.scatter(x1_1, y1_1, color = colors)
for x, y, color in zip(x1_1, y1_1, colors):
    plt.text(x, y, f'[{int(x)},{int(y)}]', color = color)
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst2[:, :, ::-1]),plt.title('Output')
plt.scatter(x1_2, y1_2, color = colors)
for x, y, color in zip(x1_2, y1_2, colors):
    plt.text(x, y, f'[{int(x)},{int(y)}]', color = color)
plt.show()
```

Final result:
[image: 2]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, because same code works fine with another image:
[image: 3]

//EDIT

The red rectangle at first image is a biggest contour. 
To find it I use these 2 functions:
adjust gamma to make image darker

```
def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):

   invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
   table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
      for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")

   return cv2.LUT(image, table)
```

Then I found all contours and took the biggest:

```
def find_biggest_cnt(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thrash = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 35 , 200, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thrash,cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]

    for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            screenCnt = approx
            break
    return screenCnt
```

And result is:
[image]

Comment: Can you please post a complete code sample? For simply reproducing the problem, it would be much easier for us to have the complete code, and the original input image. (complete code as a single executable Python script including the `import` statements...).

Comment: Draw your contour on your input image and see if matches were you want it. Then print the 4 points you use for input from the contour. You need to do some debugging by printing more and reviewing the data. What is the code you used to get your biggest contour?  Did you threshold? If so, did you check the threshold to see if it actually identified the region you wanted.

Comment: It can be better to share how you get `screenCnt2`